# How to change the "Remove Formatting" button face for TinyMCE 4

Tags: css, tinymce-4

The TinyMCE 4 button for Remove Formatting is [image], which is certainly not intuitive to me. I'd like to make the button face something more obvious, like [image] by, say assigning an image to it.  But I'm not finding anywhere to change the button face. The markup assigned to the button is

[image].

I'm not sure how that gets that Tx symbol on the button, but there it is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hey Steve, does my answer help you sufficiently or can i clarify anything futher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In skin.min.css change

```
.mce-i-removeformat:before {
   content: "\e01d"; 
}
```

to something like

```
.mce-i-removeformat:before {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rzf2.png");
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can probably remove the `background-size` and `background-repeat` if you make your image the right size

If you don't want to edit the css directly, you could just make a new css file and load it after the default one to override the settings. If you did this, you would have to override the contents to remove the original icon

Comment: Thanks Grezzo.  Yes I like the idea of using an image because then I can do something more than FMT with a line through it, like FMT with an "X: over it.  I gave you the points.  To everyone else, thank you for responding. They were all great ideas.

Answer (score 4):

These icons come from the tinymce font. for me in the tinymce source i have the fonts at

tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.woff|ttf|etc

If you added your own font file withyour own icon it should allow you to change the icon

If you inspect the css you'll notice there are two parts that control the icons being used

On the ::before inside the  tag

```
.mce-i-italic:before {
    content: "\e02b";
}
```

on the i tag itself

```
.mce-ico {
     font-family: tinymce, Arial
}
```

both comefrom skin.min.css

Comment: Hi Batavia.  Sorry for the delay.  Could you explain a bit about how I would create and add my own font file that had a character icon like an FMT with a line through it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you say that instead of new image you use :after pseudo element and remove :before one.

This is how it would look

https://jsfiddle.net/nj6yn4bq/4/

And the code

```
<button><i></i></button>

i:before { display: none; }
i:after {
    content: 'FMT';
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-style: initial;
    font-size: 15px;
}

button { 
background: linear-gradient(#FFF,#E0E0E0);
padding: 0.7em;
border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
```

}

Comment: I like that your solution uses fonts rather than an image. It will scale better than an image.